# Link to a weekday in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I'm in need of a number of small graphics that link to specific weekdays (last Friday and Saturday).

However I'm struggling to find if there's a pre-built way of doing this. The codex don't seem to give anything away.

If it's not possible, I think a wp_query that targets posts may be needed.

If anyone has any ideas how you'd fetch items from a custom post type from a specific day of the week that would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want help with creating the links or using WP_Query? - [the Codex has guidance on using time parameters with WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters)

Comment: If there's a link option, I think that would be easiest and make best use of WordPress. However I'm not sure if that's actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a querystring for your links that includes the day of the week. Check the codex pages on [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [add_query_arg](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if you need them. Perhaps create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for the page you link to.

On your page, create a new instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and set the [time parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) accordingly.

Post back with code if you still can't get it to work.